# NamingException in Glassfish7

Tags: java, glassfish, jndi, naming

I have four JNDI string values to lookup for my application. I've added them to Glassfish under Resources -> JNDI -> Custom Resources via asadmin:

```
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=dev" environment
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.String --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=www.mydomain.com" webURL
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.Boolean --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=true" isTestSystem
create-custom-resource --restype java.lang.Boolean --factoryclass org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory --property "value=true" isResetAvailable
```

These appear in my domain.xml properly, but when the app starts up it says it can't find them. For example:

```
        try
        {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup(CoreServicesConstants.DS_CONTEXT);

            environment = (String) envContext.lookup("environment");
        }
        catch (final NamingException nx)
        {
            ERROR_RECORDER.error(nx.getMessage(), nx);
        }
```

This code works with the variables in place in Tomcat 9/10 so I'm pretty sure its not the code. Unless I need to change from java:comp/env to something else?

JNDI string value lookup